# Saving audio from mp4 as wav file using Moviepy Audiofile

Tags: python, wav, moviepy

I have a video file named `'video.mp4'`. I am trying to seperate a section of audio from the video and save it as a wav file that can be used with other Python modules. I want to do this with MoviePy.

I send parameters to the `write_audiofile` function, specifying the filename, fps, nbyte, and codec.

Following the MoviePy AudioClip [docs](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/AudioClip.html), I specified the codec as `‘pcm_s32le’` for a 32-bit wav file.

```
from moviepy.editor import *

sound = AudioFileClip("video.mp4")
newsound = sound.subclip("00:00:13","00:00:15")   #audio from 13 to 15 seconds
newsound.write_audiofile("sound.wav", 44100, 2, 2000,"pcm_s32le")
```

This code generates a `.wav` file, named `'sound.wav'`.

---

### Opening the audio file in [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/)

The resulting file, `sound.wav`, can be opened in Audacity, however I run into problems when I try to use it as a wav file with other Python modules.

---

### Playing the sound file in [pygame](https://www.pygame.org)

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
sound=pygame.mixer.Sound("sound.wav")
```

The third line gives the following error:

`pygame.error: Unable to open file 'sound.wav'`

---

### Determining type of sound file using sndhdr.what()

```
import sndhdr
sndhdr.what("sound.wav")
```

The sndhdr method returned `none`
. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sndhdr.html), when this happens, the method failed to determine the type of sound data stored in the file.

---

### Reading the file with Google Speech Recognition

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
audio = "sound.wav"

with sr.AudioFile(audio) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
text= r.recognize_google(audio)
print(text)
```

This code stops execution on the second to last line:

```
ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format
```

---

Why does the audio file open in Audacity, if `sndhdr.what()` can not recognize it as an audio file type?
How can I properly export a MoviePy AudioClip as a `wav` file?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with no codec specified or with codec = 'pcms32le', the one that worked for me was **pcm_s16le**.
Note that I am using "fr-FR" language, you should probably adapt to yur needs.
here is the entire code :

```
# Python code to convert video to audio
import moviepy.editor as mp
import speech_recognition as sr

# Insert Local Video File Path
clip = mp.VideoFileClip("/tmp/data/test.mp4")

# Insert Local Audio File Path
clip.audio.write_audiofile("/tmp/data/test.wav",codec='pcm_s16le')

# initialize the recognizer
r = sr.Recognizer()

# open the file
with sr.AudioFile("/tmp/data/test.wav") as source:
    # listen for the data (load audio to memory)
    audio_data = r.record(source)
    # recognize (convert from speech to text)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language = "fr-FR")
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was trying to get a mp4 file from URL, then convert It into wav file and call Google Speech Recognition over It. Instead I used pydub to handle conversion and it worked! Here's a sample of the code:

```py
    import requests
    import io
    import speech_recognition as sr
    from pydub import AudioSegment


    # This function translate speech to text
    def speech_to_text(file):
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        audio = sr.AudioFile(file)
        with audio as source:
            speech = recognizer.record(source)
            try:
                # Call recognizer with audio and language
                text = recognizer.recognize_google(speech, language='pt-BR')
                print("Você disse: " + text)
                return text
            # If recognizer don't understand
            except:
                print("Não entendi")

    def mp4_to_wav(file):
        audio = AudioSegment.from_file(file, format="mp4")
        audio.export("audio.wav", format="wav")
        return audio

    def mp4_to_wav_mem(file):
        audio = AudioSegment.from_file_using_temporary_files(file, 'mp4')
        file = io.BytesIO()
        file = audio.export(file, format="wav")
        file.seek(0)
        return file


    url = ''
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    file = io.BytesIO(r.content)
    file = mp4_to_wav_mem(file)
    speech_to_text(file)
```

Note that I wrote two functions: mp4_to_wav and mp4_to_wav_mem. The only difference is mp4_to_wav_mem handle all files in memory and mp4_to_wav generates .wav file.

Answer (score 0):

I read the docs of MoviePy and found that the parameter `nbyte` should be consistent with `codec`. `nbyte` is for the Sample width (set to 2 for 16-bit sound, 4 for 32-bit sound). Hence, it better set `nbyte=4`, when you set `codec=pcm_s32le`.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the right method:

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip

PATH= "files/"
fileName = "nameOfYourFile.mp4"
newFileName = "nameOfTheNewFile"
Ext = "wav"
AudioFileClip(os.path.join(PATH, f"{fileName}")).write_audiofile(os.path.join(PATH, f"{newFileName}.{Ext}"))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, consider including an explanation of how and why it works to make this answer more useful for future visitors to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is very easy to understand.

```
from moviepy.editor import *
input_file = "../Database/myvoice.mp4"
output_file = "../Database/myvoice.wav"
sound = AudioFileClip(input_file)
sound.write_audiofile(output_file, 44100, 2, 2000,"pcm_s32le")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.